# Make only the sectional heading use Times; the rest keep the regular font

Tags: fonts, sectioning, chapters

How can I make all the `\chapter` (`\mychapter`), `\section` and  `\subsection` headings use the Times font but keep the rest of the text in a LaTeX font?

Comment: In my opinion, this mixture is ugly, but you can do it with `titlesec`.

Comment: What have you tried? What is `\mychapter`?

Comment: I used \mychapter so the number would disappear in front of it (in the heading and in the table of contents) e.g. \mychapter{1}{Methodology}

Comment: I hope you mean by 'like "times"' just a different font. Because the actual Times font makes a really bad font for headings and does not fit the default CMR at all.

Answer (score 5):

In this code you have the Times New Roman (`\fontfamily{ptm}`) for the names of the `\chapter`, `\section` and `\subsection` and the rest of the text with Computer modern (CM). 
If, one day, you desires changed the font family of the chapter, section and subsection, you choose your preferite *fontcode* and put it into the brackets of `\fontfamily{...}`. one of this font code (link ):

For example, if you like **Utopia/Fourier** then you will put `\fontfamily{put}`. Here there is a minimal table of the font typefaces; other table you will find it into this [site](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces) (for example).

```
********************************************************
*Name*             *fontcode*
Adobe Times Roman: ptr
Utopia/Fourier: put
Computer Modern Roman: cmr
Computer Modern Sans: cmss
Computer Modern Bright: cmbr
Computer Modern Typewriter: cmtt
Adobe Palatino: ppl
Bookman: pbk
Adobe New Century Schoolbok: pnc
Bera Serif: fve
URW Classico: uop
Adobe Helvetica: phv
ITC Avant Garde Gothic: pag
Bera Sans: fvs
Adobe Courier: pcr
Helvetica: phv
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{}  
\begin{document}
\chapter{First name}
\lipsum[1][2-3] $a^2=b^2+c^2$.
\section{Second name}
Another formula $\Delta p=m\Delta v$.
\subsection{Third name}
Another formula $L=mrv$.

\end{document}
```